# how to get the string value from input stream?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have android application, in android application I have executed select query on mysql database table.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mywebsite.com/select.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();   
            //if(compare is value here)
```

here I want to check `InputStream is` value.

when I execute `http://www.mywebsite.com/select.php` on browser i get output value like `{name  : ashu}` or `null`

but how can I compare this is my code as i'm unable to check `is==null` :(

Comment: 5 ways to convert InputStream to String in Java http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/convert-inputstream-to-string-java-example-tutorial.html

Comment: and probably you need a HttpGet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your Manifest file

Comment: Take a look at this mybe It can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097824/null-pointer-exception-http-entity